# How i can check currentQueue is main queue.?

Tags: ios, nsoperationqueue

I am working with `Multiple NSOperationQueue` for creating `Views`.

For creating `UIViews` i am using `Multiple Classes`.

i am creating `View` in background but now i want to `Add as Subview in UIScrollView` for that i need to switch to `Main queue`.

I am adding in `UIScrollView` like below.

```
[self.scrollView addSubview:pageView];
```

for creating `NSOperationQueue` i am using following way.

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [queue addOperationWithBlock:^{

        // My code for background process.
        // Calling other class method for adding view as subview.
    }];
```

How can i check `[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]` is `mainQueue`.?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] == [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
```